# Add the latest github release identifier, date and validation date into a (R)markdown file

Tags: github, r-markdown, github-actions, markdown

I would like to add the latest Github release identifier and date, as well as the latest date in which a workflow was executed successfully to a (R)markdown file.

For example, for the repository https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap,
I would like to add to my (R)markdown file the following:

```
This is the release {release_id}, published on {release_date}.
The software was validated successfully on {myworkflow.latest_successfully_date}.
```

Where `{release_id}`, `{release_date}` and `{myworkflow.latest_successfully_date}` are the information about the identifier of the release (*v.5.3.2* in the example repository), the date of the release (*14 September 2023* in the example repository) and the date of the latest successful run for the `myworkflow` (*11:29 AM GMT+1* for the, let's say, *bundlewatch* workflow in the example repository), respectively.

Can you help me? Please, provide a detailed answer with some reference, so I can understand why it works and how I can extend the solution to similar situations. I'm an intermediate R user with very limited knowledge of git and HTML and almost no knowledge of javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: One possible solution could be to parse the markdown file, replace the contents of the section that you want to update, and commit it in your release workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a report on the current version might be complicated.  You might have uncommitted changes in your local copy, you might have commits that haven't been pushed to Github, and you might have tags that are different from the tags on Github.  You need a series of queries to answer all of these questions.

The `gert` package can get information from a local git repository, and `gh` can work with the Github API to get Github information.

Using those, I put together this function to generate a report on the current state of a local repository.  It's not formatted for R Markdown, and there may be things that are different in your repository than the assumptions I made.  But it's a start.

```r
stopifnot(requireNamespace("gert"),
          requireNamespace("gh"))

versionReport <- function(repo = ".", max = 100, remotename = "origin") {
  
  changes <- gert::git_status(repo = repo)
  
  branch <- gert::git_branch(repo = repo)
  
  log <- gert::git_log(repo = repo, max = max)[, 
                                                c("commit", "author", "time")]
  
  tags <- gert::git_tag_list(repo = repo)[, c("commit", "name")]
  log <- merge(log, tags, by = "commit", all.x = TRUE,
               all.y = FALSE)
  
  remote <- gert::git_remote_list(repo = repo)
  remote <- subset(remote, name == remotename)
  
  if (nrow(remote)) {
    remotels <- gert::git_remote_ls(remote = remotename, 
                                    repo = repo)[, c("oid", "ref")]
    names(remotels) <- c("commit", "remoteref")
    remotetags <- subset(remotels, grepl("^refs/tags", remoteref))
  
    log <- merge(log, remotetags, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
  }
  o <- order(log$time, decreasing = TRUE)
  log <- log[o, ]
  remotetags <- subset(log, !is.na(name))
  
  if (nrow(remote) && nrow(remotetags)) {
    ref <- sub("https://github.com", "/repos", remote$url)
    
    releases <- try(releases <- gh::gh(paste0(ref, "/releases")))
    if (inherits(releases, "try-error")) 
      releases <- NULL
    else {
      releases <- data.frame(name = sapply(releases, function(x) x$tag_name),
                             release = sapply(releases,
                                              function(x) x$name),
                             published = as.Date(sapply(releases,
                                                        function(x) x$published_at)))
      remotetags <- merge(remotetags, releases, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
      o <- order(remotetags$time, decreasing = TRUE)
      remotetags <- remotetags[o, ]
    }
  }

  result <- structure(list(repo = normalizePath(repo),
                           time = Sys.time(),
                           changes = changes, 
                           branch = branch,
                           log = log, 
                           remote = remote,
                           remotetags = remotetags),
                 class = "gitVersionInfo")
}
  
print.gitVersionInfo <- function(x, ...) {

  cat("Report on ", x$repo, "\n",
      "  at: ", format(x$time), "\n\n")
  
  if (nrow(changes <- x$changes))
    cat("Uncommitted files: \n",
        paste(changes$file, collapse = ", "), "\n\n")

  cat("git branch: ", x$branch, "\n\n")

  log <- x$log
  cat("Latest commit:  \n",
      "  SHA:    ", log$commit[1], "\n",
      "  Author: ", log$author[1], "\n",
      "  Time:   ", format(log$time[1]), "\n\n")

  tags <- log[!is.na(log$name),]
  
  if (nrow(tags)) {
    tag <- tags[1,]
    cat("Most recent local tag:  \n", 
        "  Name: ", tag$name, "\n",
        "  SHA:  ", tag$commit, "\n",
        "  Time: ", format(tag$time), "\n\n")
  } else
    cat("No recent tags.\n\n")

  if (nrow(remote <- x$remote))
    cat("remote:\n", 
        "  name: ", remote$name, "\n",
        "  url:  ", remote$url, "\n\n")
  
  if (nrow(remotetags <- x$remotetags)) {
    remotetag <- basename(remotetags[1, "remoteref"])
    if (remotetag != tags[1, "name"])
      cat("Most recent remote tag:  \n",
          "  Name: ", remotetag, "\n",
          "  SHA:  ", remotetags[1, "commit"], "\n",
          "  Time: ", format(remotetags[1, "time"]), "\n\n")
    else
      cat("Same remote tag.\n\n")
  } else
    cat("No recent remote tags.\n\n")

  releases <- subset(remotetags, !is.na(release))
  if (nrow(releases))
    cat("Github release:  \n",
        "  name:      ", releases$name[1], "\n",
        "  SHA:       ", releases$commit[1], "\n",
        "  published: ", format(releases$published[1]), "\n\n")
  else
    catlf("No Github release found.\n\n")
}

report <- versionReport(".")
print(report)

#> Report on  .../bootstrap
#>   at:  2023-11-19 12:00:56
#> 
#> Uncommitted files:  .gitignore, bootstrap.Rproj
#> 
#> git branch: "main"
#> 
#> Latest commit:  
#>   SHA:     e4f0d61c8fe67e041729f8295339020969677a9c
#>   Author:  Julien Déramond <juderamond@gmail.com>
#>   Time:    2023-11-18 03:52:03
#> 
#> Most recent local tag:  
#>   Name:  v5.3.2
#>   SHA:   344e912d04b5b6a04482113eff20ab416ff01048
#>   Time:  2023-09-14 10:19:27
#> 
#> Origin is  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
#> 
#> Same remote tag.
#> 
#> Github release:  
#>   id:    v5.3.2
#>   date:  2023-09-14
```